# Issue with QTableView Edit Mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I've subclassed a QStandardItemModel:

```
class PPSTableEditModel(QStandardItemModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PPSTableEditModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel()
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(5)
        self.proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxy.setFilterFixedString("0")
        self.editmode = None
        self.history = []

    def edit_record(self, qndx):

        #qndx is passed from a QTableView class and contains view.currentIndex()

        self.editmode = 2
        del self.history[:]
        for ndx in range(0, self.columnCount()):
            self.history.append(self.item(qndx.row(),ndx).data(Qt.DisplayRole))
        self.process_record(qndx) #<---- This works

        #ix = self.index(qndx.row(),2)
        #self.process_record(ix) #<---- This causes the error

    def process_record(self, pndx):
        self.parent().tbl_View.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(pndx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        self.parent().tbl_View.edit(pndx)
```

The issue I am having is from the `edit_record` method I pass the `qndx`to `process_record` and the view goes into edit mode properly; however, if I attempt to set the starting (by reassigning the qndx) column I get an error:

```
edit: index was invalid
edit: editing failed
```

*** EDIT ***
Attempted to map to the proxy index for editing and I am still getting the same error:

```
def edit_record(self, qndx):
        self.editmode = 2
        del self.history[:]
        for ndx in range(0, self.columnCount()):
            self.history.append(self.item(qndx.row(),ndx).data(Qt.DisplayRole))
        ix = qndx if not self.proxy else self.proxy.mapToSource(qndx)
        self.process_record(ix)
```

*** EDIT ***
MCVE:

```
import uuid,sys
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class PPSTableEditModel(QStandardItemModel):
    model_loaded = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PPSTableEditModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.proxy = None

    def edit_record(self, qndx):
        ix = qndx if not self.proxy else self.proxy.mapToSource(qndx)
        self.process_record(ix)

    def process_record(self, pndx):
        self.parent().tbl_View.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(pndx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        self.parent().tbl_View.edit(pndx)


class SclDataModel(PPSTableEditModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(5)
        self.proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxy.setFilterFixedString("0")

    def load_data(self, parentid):        
        query = QSqlQuery()
        query.prepare('SELECT * FROM scldata WHERE svcdataid=?')
        query.addBindValue(parentid)
        query.exec_()
        while query.next():
            record = []
            for ndx in range(0, query.record().count()):
                item = QStandardItem()
                item.setData(query.value(ndx), Qt.DisplayRole)
                record.append(item)
            record.append(QStandardItem("0"))
            self.insertRow(self.rowCount(), record)
        self.model_loaded.emit()


class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(600, 297)
        self.tbl_View = QTableView(self)
        self.line = QFrame(self)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
        self.spacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.view_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.view_layout.addWidget(self.tbl_View)
        self.view_layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.model = SclDataModel(self)
        self.parentid = None
        self.setup_view()
        self.setup_connections()

    def setup_view(self):
        self.tbl_View.setModel(self.model.proxy)
        self.tbl_View.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tbl_View.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tbl_View.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tbl_View.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tbl_View.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(22)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.tbl_View.doubleClicked.connect(self.edit_record)
        self.model.model_loaded.connect(self.format_view)

    def set_parent(self, parentid):
        self.parentid = parentid
        self.model.load_data(self.parentid)

    def format_view(self):
        if self.model.rowCount():
            header = ["recorid", "svcdataid", "Start Amount", "End Amount", "Rate", "deleteflag"]
            for n in range(0, len(header)):
                self.model.setHeaderData(n, Qt.Horizontal, header[n])
            self.tbl_View.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.tbl_View.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnWidth(4, 85)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(0, True)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(1, True)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(5, True)

    def set_parent_record(self, parentid):
        self.parentid = parentid
        self.model.load_data(self.parentid)

    def edit_record(self):
        qndx = self.tbl_View.currentIndex()
        self.model.edit_record(qndx)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = SclDataBrowse()
db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
db.setHostName("myhost")
db.setUserName("myusr")
db.setPassword("mypassword")
db.setDatabaseName("mydbname")
db.open()
mainWin.show()
mainWin.set_parent("a5865717-e125-11e8-80c0-d4ae52cc00a8")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

*** EDIT ***
Seems to be something with the `QSortFilterProxyModel` though I can't pin it down. Passing the index to `process_record` without mapping it through the proxy allows me to edit but the underlying data is incorrect.

```
*** EDIT ***
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class PPSTableEditModel(QStandardItemModel):
    model_loaded = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PPSTableEditModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.proxy = None

    def edit_record(self, qndx):
        ix = qndx.sibling(qndx.row(), 2)
        self.process_record(ix)
        #ix = qndx if not self.proxy else self.proxy.mapToSource(qndx)
        #self.process_record(ix)

    def delete_record(self, qndx):
        ix = qndx if not self.proxy else self.proxy.mapToSource(qndx)
        self.item(ix.row(),5).setData("1",Qt.DisplayRole)

    def process_record(self, pndx):
        for ndx in range(0,self.columnCount()):
            print('{0},{1}----->{2}'.format(pndx.row(),ndx,self.item(pndx.row(),ndx).data(Qt.DisplayRole)))
        self.parent().tbl_View.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(pndx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
        self.parent().tbl_View.edit(pndx)


class SclDataModel(PPSTableEditModel):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataModel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.proxy = QSortFilterProxyModel(self)
        self.proxy.setSourceModel(self)
        self.proxy.setFilterKeyColumn(5)
        self.proxy.setDynamicSortFilter(True)
        self.proxy.setFilterFixedString("0")

    def load_data(self, parentid):
        data = (
            {"recordid": "1", "svcdataid": 1, "samount": .01, "eamount": 5000, "rate": .065, "delflag": "0"},
            {"recordid": "2", "svcdataid": 1, "samount": 5000.01, "eamount": 10000, "rate": .065, "delflag": "0"},
            {"recordid": "3", "svcdataid": 1, "samount": 10000.01, "eamount": 15000, "rate": .060, "delflag": "0"},
            {"recordid": "4", "svcdataid": 1, "samount": 15000.01, "eamount": 20000, "rate": .055, "delflag": "0"},
            {"recordid": "5", "svcdataid": 1, "samount": 20000.01, "eamount": 99999, "rate": .05, "delflag": "0"}
        )
        for ndx,rec in enumerate(data):
            record = []
            for key in rec:
                item = QStandardItem()
                item.setData(rec[key], Qt.DisplayRole)
                record.append(item)
            self.insertRow(self.rowCount(), record)
        self.model_loaded.emit()


class SclDataBrowse(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SclDataBrowse, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(600, 297)
        self.tbl_View = QTableView(self)
        self.line = QFrame(self)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Sunken)
        self.spacer = QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.view_layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.view_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.view_layout.addWidget(self.tbl_View)
        self.view_layout.addWidget(self.line)
        self.btn_layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.btn_layout.setContentsMargins(6, 6, 6, 6)
        self.btn_delete = QPushButton()
        self.btn_delete.setText("Delete")
        self.btn_layout.addWidget(self.btn_delete)
        self.view_layout.addLayout(self.btn_layout)
        self.model = SclDataModel(self)
        self.parentid = None
        self.setup_view()
        self.setup_connections()

    def setup_view(self):
        self.tbl_View.setModel(self.model.proxy)
        self.tbl_View.setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.tbl_View.setSelectionMode(QAbstractItemView.SingleSelection)
        self.tbl_View.setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.tbl_View.verticalHeader().setVisible(False)
        self.tbl_View.verticalHeader().setDefaultSectionSize(22)

    def setup_connections(self):
        self.tbl_View.doubleClicked.connect(self.edit_record)
        self.btn_delete.clicked.connect(self.delete_record)
        self.model.model_loaded.connect(self.format_view)

    def set_parent(self, parentid):
        self.parentid = parentid
        self.model.load_data(self.parentid)

    def format_view(self):
        if self.model.rowCount():
            header = ["recorid", "svcdataid", "Start Amount", "End Amount", "Rate", "deleteflag"]
            for n in range(0, len(header)):
                self.model.setHeaderData(n, Qt.Horizontal, header[n])
            self.tbl_View.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.tbl_View.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnWidth(4, 85)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(0, True)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(1, True)
            self.tbl_View.setColumnHidden(5, True)

    def set_parent_record(self, parentid):
        self.parentid = parentid
        self.model.load_data(self.parentid)

    def edit_record(self):
        qndx = self.tbl_View.currentIndex()
        self.model.edit_record(qndx)

    def delete_record(self):
        qndx = self.tbl_View.currentIndex()
        self.model.delete_record(qndx)



app = QApplication(sys.argv)
mainWin = SclDataBrowse()
mainWin.show()
mainWin.set_parent("a5865717-e125-11e8-80c0-d4ae52cc00a8")
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

With this code, there are 5 entries in the table.  If you delete, say, the second record the filters correctly hides the "deleted" record.  Now double click on the 3rd or 4th row and the data outputted in `process_record` reports the correct row but the data associated with that row is incorrect.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: MCVE posted.  Thanks Eyllanesc,

Comment: please there are many things that are not defined by example: `btn_New`, `SclDataDelegate`, etc, please correct your MCVE adding also the imports and the main.

Comment: Stripped it down a little more....see if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your code, you want to access an index that is in the same row but in the second column, that is, it is a sibling of the `QModelIndex`, so you must use the sibling function:

```
def edit_record(self, qndx):
    ix = qndx.sibling(qndx.row(), 2)
    self.process_record(ix)
```

---

The problem is because you are using the item to obtain the data, `QTableView` does not know the k, it only knows the model that has been established, that is, the `QSortFilterProxyModel`, so the QModelIndex that requires the `edit()` and `selectionModel().SetCurrentIndex()` must be the `QSortFilterProxyModel` so that's why my initial solution works, but in your impression you are using the `PPSTableEditModel` model so the solution is to use the proxy but it is not necessary to store it since the `QModelIndex` saves a model reference to belongs:

```
def process_record(self, pndx):
    model = pndx.model()
    for ndx in range(model.columnCount()):
        print('{0},{1}----->{2}'.format(pndx.row(), ndx, model.index(pndx.row(),ndx).data(Qt.DisplayRole)))
    self.parent().tbl_View.selectionModel().setCurrentIndex(pndx, QItemSelectionModel.Select)
    self.parent().tbl_View.edit(pndx)
```

Comment: Eyllanesc, the solution worked; however, if the table is filtered, an edit is returning the wrong record data.  Filter one of the rows with a "1" in the last column.  Double click any record under the one you filtered and the data is from another row.

Comment: @Elcid_91 I have created my test data and I see that it works correctly, you could explain yourself better.

Comment: Made another edit to exemplify the issue.  Thanks eyllanesc.

Comment: Thanks eyllanesc.  I now understand the modeling.  Cheers!